# Background-color not changing with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use a forEach loop to loop through a grid of boxes and change the box color when clicked on. However for some reason, every other css styling works BUT backgroundcolor.

- I tried redoing my code as well as using a for loop but it didnt work either.

here is my codepen with my code: 
https://codepen.io/Fairy121/pen/dBGYRQ

```js
var sqrs = document.querySelectorAll('.sqr');

function changeCol(event) {
  console.log(event.target);
  event.target.classList.toggle('my_choice');
}

sqrs.forEach(sqr => sqr.addEventListener('click', changeCol));
```

```css
.my_choice {
  border: 3px solid black;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='sqr-grid'>
  <div class='sqr'>0</div>
  <div class='sqr'>1</div>
  <div class='sqr'>2</div>
  <div class='sqr'>3</div>
  <div class='sqr'>4</div>
  <div class='sqr'>5</div>
  <div class='sqr'>6</div>
  <div class='sqr'>7</div>
  <div class='sqr'>8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine here. Whatever the problem is, there isn't enough information in the question to reproduce it.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: Move ```.my_choice``` after ```.sqr``` in CSS.

Comment: the squares originally have a background color of orange. I am trying to make it change green. But only the other two css stylings take effect.

Comment: @MysteriousShadow - They don't have a background of orange (provide a [mcve] **in the question itself**)

Comment: Thank you! I didnt realize it was such a simple fix.

Comment: sqr has to be before my_choice : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dBGGpy

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:-

```
var sqrs = document.querySelectorAll('.sqr');
sqrs.forEach(sqr => {

  sqr.addEventListener('click', function(){sqr.classList.toggle('my_choice'); });
});
```

**Note:-** In [this](https://codepen.io/Fairy121/pen/dBGYRQ) link `.my_choice` style is empty so add `background:green` & also remove `.one`

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in your css code on code pen:

```css
.one
.my_choice{
  
}
```

In fact, you can use only one event listener and check the event target to dynamically toggle `my_choice` css class for any element with `sqr` css class.

```js
document.querySelector('.sqr-grid').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if (target.classList.contains('sqr')) {
    target.classList.toggle('my_choice');
  }
});
```

Please, take a look at the [demo](https://jsbin.com/gubalekizo/5/edit?css,js,output).

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the class attribute

```
var sqrs = document.querySelectorAll('.sqr');

function changeCol(event) {
 console.log(event.target);
  event.target.setAttribute('class','my_choice');
}

sqrs.forEach(sqr => {
  sqr.addEventListener('click',changeCol);
});
```

Comment: No, they don't. `classList` is fine. You can see it working in the live demo in the question.

Comment: It is well supported [even in Internet Explorer](https://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist).